# Subset part of data based on values

Tags: r, subset

I have a very large dataset on returned products and for creating an explanatory model I need the data to consist of half products being returned (1) and half of the products not being returned (0), hence they are given as binary variables. How do I randomly subset this out of the data?

The following is a part of the dataset

```
> dput(head(dat, 100))
structure(list(data5.order_id = c(24409499, 24409499, 37018675, 
49812254, 72349794, 121649820, 121649820, 123680104, 123680104, 
123680104, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 
156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 
156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 
156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 156423543, 169218518, 
169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 
169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 
169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 169218518, 198566821, 
198566821, 198566821, 198566821, 204651617, 204651617, 225070398, 
244297553, 244297553, 244297553, 244297553, 244297553, 244297553, 
264159404, 286533497, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 
302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 
302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 
302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 
302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 302587170, 308442395, 308442395, 
308442395, 312804245, 318656210, 360581093, 360581093, 381985214, 
381985214), data5.returnyesno = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), data5.customer_id = c(3150040285, 3150040285, 
1437583473, 319353305, 620027539, 3023138737, 3023138737, 2519171220, 
2519171220, 2519171220, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 
4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 
4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 
4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 4599523733, 
1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 
1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 
1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 1816785895, 
1131020953, 1131020953, 1131020953, 1131020953, 2335167491, 2335167491, 
1327858307, 330788549, 330788549, 330788549, 330788549, 330788549, 
330788549, 3230395728, 3888591660, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 
1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 
1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 
1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 
1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 1158650034, 908821356, 
908821356, 908821356, 1155228355, 684878789, 3389325926, 3389325926, 
1808359289, 1808359289)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What would you prefer to see to understand? My data set is so large that I cannot provide the entire set

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give an example input / output, so I created an example.

```
### create some fake data ###
library(data.table)
n = 10000

df1 = data.table(
    returned = as.logical(sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=n)), 
    some_other_variable = rnorm(n)
    )

## the size of the sampled dataset you want to create ##
sample_size = 1000

### select rows which have been returned and not returned ##
true_rows = sample(which(df1$returned == T), sample_size/2)
false_rows = sample(which(df1$returned == F), sample_size/2)

## subset these rows from the original
df2 = df1[c(true_rows, false_rows)]
```

Comment: Oh sorry I indeed forgot, however for my dataset I also have 32 other columns which data needs to be saved. The problem however is now that since there are less than half true rows, it cannot fill the entire size created by sample_size/2, which gives an error.

Comment: @Estelle could you provide a small sample of your data in the same proportions as the true data using ``dput()``. Thanks.

Comment: This gives a really large output, since the data consists of 157262 observations, is there any way I could show it partially?

Comment: Yes, try something like ``dput(head(data, 100))``.

Comment: I included it! Hopefully it is useful